# Не всегда срабатывает scrollTo

Tags: java, android

Если запускаю метод softReset содержащий scrollTo(0,0)

```
public void softReset() {
    scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

внутри своего класса TableView (extends View), например по двойному тапу onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event), то все срабатывает как должно.

```
    @Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
    softReset();
    return true;
}
```

Если запускаю тот же метод снаружи из MainActivity по кнопке "назад" onBackPressed(), то метод softReset запускается, но scrollTo(0,0) в нем не срабатывет, но если нажать кнопку "назад" второй раз то срабатывает.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            table.softReset();
    }
```

Пробовал запускать метод дважды подряд

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
           table.softReset();
           table.softReset();
    }
```

все равно не помогает.

Никаких новых потоков я не открывал, так как приложение очень легкое. Может быть именно в этом проблема?

Добавлено 09.09 13:20
Обнаружил когда баг проявляется, а когда нет. Если один раз крутануть (onFling) и отпустить палец до остановки скроллинга, а потом нажать "назад" - то бага нет, метод scrollTo() срабатывает и все возвращается нормально. Если двигать, а потом отпустить и после этого нажать "назад" то баг есть.

Comment: Пробовали отладить этот код? Может логов понаставлять и посмотреть.

Comment: Не могу сообразить как проверить что происходит в недрах метода scrollTo(). Обнаружил когда баг проявляется, а когда нет.

Comment: Обнаружил когда баг проявляется, а когда нет. Если один раз крутануть (onFling) и отпустить палец до остановки скроллинга, а потом нажать "назад" - то бага нет, метод scrollTo() срабатывает и все возвращается нормально. Если двигать, а потом отпустить и после этого нажать "назад" то баг есть.

Comment: не помешает после [вызвать реализацию onBackPressed()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337567/7566397) самой системы

Answer (score 0):

Надо вызывать `post()`:

```
table.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        table.softReset();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Что-то все равно не работает.

Comment: Я вот думаю. Изначально я создаю table и в нем происходит выполнение методов. Потом я со стороны MainActivity пинаю свой table. table в это время вроде ничего не делает, но все-таки почему он вообще должен реагировать? Может быть в него надо какой-то слушатель вставить? Хотя на второе нажатие реагирует нормально... На первое нажатие может дернутся на полстрочки.